# PHP, async PUT request with guzzle library

Tags: php, rest, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm trying to make an async put request but something doesn't work, call doesn't execute, there is no error, promise returns "{}".

```
protected $guzzle;
function __construct()
{
    $this->guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);
}
```

And there is a call itself:

```
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('PUT', $call->callback_url,
        [
            'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $hash,
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'paymentStatusId' => "$orderstatusID"
        ]);

    $promise = $this->guzzle->sendAsync($request)->then(
        function (\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) use ($call) {

            if ($response->getBody() == '1') {
                $call->shopware_response = $response->getBody();
                $call->status = 'success';
            } else {
                $call->status = 'to_renewal';
            }
            $call->save();
        }
    );

    $promise->wait();
```

Thanks in advance for answers!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, you probably want to add more error handlers to it.

If I were you:
->then(...)
->otherwise(function ($error) { /* log the error somehow */ })

And also some small changes:

- `$response->getBody();` to `$response->getBody()->getContents();` (to get a string, not a stream)
- for basic auth it might be better to use `auth` option of `sendAsync()` method